# Rails - Show action for nested resource is deleting the record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a simple web app with a typical User model & Profile model.  The user model has_one profile & the profile model belongs_to user.  All is going pretty well as I am basically following Michael Hartl's tutorial (except he uses has_many for microposts).

So here's the deal.  I create a user, then create a profile.  I know both records exist b/c I verify their presence in my sqlite3 db browser.  However, as soon as I try to render the show view by visiting -> localhost/3000/profiles/1, I get the error shown below.  But the even weirder part is that now when I check my db, the profile record is gone.  Please help!

Note:  I have a feeling it has something to do with dependent destroy (b/c removing it will eliminate this issue), but I have no idea why.  Furthermore, I think I want dependent destroy anyway.  I don't want any stray profile records if there are no corresponding users, right?

Routes

```
resources :users
resources :profiles
```

Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

ProfilesController

```
def new
  @profile = current_user.build_profile
end

def create
  @profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile])
  if @profile.save
    flash[:success] = "Profile created!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show 
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end
```

views/profiles/show.html.erb

```
<p>Display Name: <%= @profile.display_name %></p>
```

This is the error message I get when I try to visit -> localhost/3000/profiles/1

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#show

Couldn't find Profile without an ID
```

Comment: try to "puts params.inspect", in show action before find, and see what's being passed in, then post it

Comment: is there a reason you don't have an index action? if you did, that could help because it should list all profile (via Profile.all).

Comment: Hi Said.  I added "puts params.inspect" as a line above "@profile = Profile.find(params[:id]) in the show action.  Is this how you wanted me to do it?  Anyway, when I visited the url, I got the same error.

Comment: Hi Callmeed. I created an index action & index view to test this.  Again, when I visited /profiles, it also deleted the single profile record I previously had in the db.